# sync time on linux using ntp and persist it

Tags: linux, time, ntp

on linux to sync time with ntp you say

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

however after reboots, the time gets reset to some odd value again. is there a way to persist the changes?

how do I set the computer clock to the correct time and then keep it correct after reboot?

Answer (score 10):

As you discovered, `ntpdate` is a one-shot deal.

You want [`ntpd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd).

Comment: ntpd alone will not help maintaining the time across reboots (it will only correct the time some seconds(?) after a reboot, and will not work if there's no net connection).

Comment: However, ntpd can be forced to sync time during initial start, just like ntpdate does: just use `ntpd -g`. It makes `ntpd` to forcibly sync to clock, no matter the time difference. This happens only once, after the initial sync ntpd will run as usual. And `ntpdate` does no good either if there's no network connection.

Comment: @JannePikkarainen: True, ntpdate does no good if there's no network connection, but `hwclock` does. You need to use hwclock if you want the correct time right after booting.

Answer (score 7):

1. Firstly make sure your system has time/date correct.
   (ntp/timezone)
2. Then, run `hwclock --systohc` (Theoretically this should not be necessary, as most Linux systems do this automatically on shutdown, but it can't hurt.)

This should reset your computer's [real-time clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) (RTC, a.k.a "hardware clock" or "BIOS clock") to the system time, and should make your sync persistent across reboot.

Modern Linux systems automatically set the system time from the RTC during bootup, thus setting the RTC makes sure the system time is correct right after booting. Using `ntpd` or similar to synchronize with a time server is a good addition, to keep the clock accurate in the longer run.

Comment: I took the liberty of expanding your already good answer a bit. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @sleske no probs !! whatever it takes to be more readable and better

Answer (score 2):

If any other solution works, check the following as last resource.

How old is the computer that is showing the Issue?

If it's an old computer, you should check if the motherboard battery is still with charge (yes, there is a little clock battery that allows the computer to hold some data as time/date across reboots).

If it's discharged, a simple battery replacement will fix it for good.

Comment: Good point. Note that problems with the clock battery will only affect the RTC / hardware clock. The system clock used by the OS is maintained independently.